# Navigate the DOM with CasperJS

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I have a web page which has several `tr`s and within each `tr` there are several `td`s. The structure looks like shown below

```
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<td class="td1" style="text-align:left">TGHD03WYD15UGS</td>

<td class="td1" style="text-align:left">
    <font style="font-weight:bold"> TicketType</font>
    :The Grand Hotel, New Delhi,
    <font style="font-weight:bold"> FirstName</font>
    :Sanjali,
    <font style="font-weight:bold"> LastName</font>
    :Garg
</td>
```

I am able to get the list of `tr`s using

```
this.getElementsInfo('selector');
```

When I iterate over the list I do get the `tr`s but `td`s show up only in html format. What I would like to have is `td` objects which can be accessed using properties. The same would hold true in case of getting the inner objects from the last `td` which holds font tag objects.

If I can navigate through the DOM as is possible in real javascript scenario, I would be able to get all the objects and will be able to access properties in them.

So far it doesn't looks possible in CasperJS. All I get in html property which gives me a string representation of that element, rather than giving me the object itself. I would like to navigate to the children of the element as in real javascript.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate the DOM by using [`casper.evaluate`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) or variants. It executes the JavaScript given as a callback in the page context which is sandboxed. You cannot pass complex objects like DOM nodes. The [docs](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) say:

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

Further reading:

[Understanding the evaluate function in CasperJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216243/understanding-evaluate-function-casperjs)
[Why doesn't this.evaluate return DOM nodes correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353431/why-doesnt-this-evaluate-return-dom-nodes-correctly)
[Iterating over a grid with CasperJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842979/iterating-over-a-grid-with-casperjs)